# Reusing loopback models from another Node app

Tags: loopbackjs

I have developed a API server on the top of loopback.

**What is the best way of reusing the models from another Node app?**

I managed to do it by just copying parts of the server.js code of original app, but this will probably do a lot of stuff I don't actually need:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Here I can use my models
  app.models.MyModel.find({
    where: {userId: 1}
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    else {
      console.log(result);  // This works!!!!
    }
  });

  // Add more specific code
  // ...

});
```

Is there a better (lighter) way to use those models?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to connect and use another Node app and if that's the case, see if & how [`loopback-connector-remote`](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-connector.html) can help you.
If that's not the case, could you please explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to reuse the models from another Node app. I've read about remoting and I find it too "heavy". I would just like to use just the DB access part, that is the models directly (please see my example). I don't want the whole server to run in order to "expose" those methods.

I am looking for a minimal scaffolding for such a purpose.